# Arithmetic with decimal option types

Tags: f#

I'm trying to do some mathematical operations with `decimal options` on a custom type:

```
type LineItem = {Cost: decimal option; Price: decimal option; Qty: decimal option}

let discount = 0.25M

let createItem (c, p, q) = 
    {Cost = c; Price = p; Qty = q}

let items =
    [
        (Some 1M  ,    None   , Some 1M)
        (Some 3M  ,    Some 2.0M   , None)
        (Some 5M  ,    Some 3.0M   , Some 5M)
        (None  ,    Some 1.0M   , Some 2M)
        (Some 11M  ,   Some 2.0M   , None)
    ] 
    |> List.map createItem
```

I can do some very simple arithmetic with

```
items
|> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Price 
                        |> Option.map (fun x -> discount * x))
```

which gives me

```
val it : seq<decimal option> =
  seq [null; Some 0.500M; Some 0.750M; Some 0.250M; ...]
```

If I try to actually calculate the thing I need

```
items
|> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Price 
                        |> Option.map (fun x -> discount * x)
                        |> Option.map (fun x -> x - (line.Cost 
                                                        |> Option.map (fun x -> x))) 
                        |> Option.map (fun x -> x * (line.Qty 
                                                        |> Option.map (fun x -> x))))
```

I get the error

```
error FS0001: Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    'a option    
is not compatible with type
    decimal    
The type ''a option' is not compatible with the type 'decimal'
```

where I would have expected a `seq<decimal option>`.

I must be missing something but I can't seem to spot whatever it is I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem you have is the following code:

```f#
(line.Cost |> Option.map (fun x -> x))
```

The lambda function `(fun x -> x)` already exists. This is the `id` function. It just returns whatever you have unchanged. You also could write the code you have like this:

```f#
(line.Cost |> Option.map id)
```

And the next thing. Mapping over the `id` function makes no sense. You unwrap whatever is inside the option, apply the `id` function to it. What didn't change the decimal at all. Then you wrap the decimal again in an option. You also can just write:

```f#
line.Cost
```

and completely remove the `Option.map` as it does nothing.

So the code you have here:

```f#
|> Option.map (fun x -> x - (line.Cost |> Option.map (fun x -> x)))
```

is identical to:

```f#
|> Option.map (fun x -> x - line.Cost)
```

This obviously does not work because here you try to subtract `x` a `decimal` with `line.Cost` a `option decimal`. So you get a type-error.

I guess what you really want to do is to subtract `line.Cost` from `line.Price` if `line.Cost` is present, otherwise you want to preserve `line.Price` unchanged.

One way would be just to provide a default value for `line.Costs` that can be used and have no effect on the subtraction. For example you could use the value `0` for subtraction if `line.Costs` is `None`.

So you also could write something like this instead:

```f#
|> Option.map (fun x -> x - (defaultArg line.Cost 0m))
```

A default value for multiplication would be `1m`. So you overall end with.

```f#
items
|> Seq.map (fun line -> 
    line.Price 
    |> Option.map (fun x -> discount * x)
    |> Option.map (fun x -> x - (defaultArg line.Cost 0m)) 
    |> Option.map (fun x -> x * (defaultArg line.Qty 1m)))
```

The above code for example returns:

```f#
[None; Some -2.500M; Some -21.250M; Some 0.500M; Some -10.500M]
```

If your goal is that a whole computation turns into `None` as soon a single
value is `None`. I would just add `map2` as a helper function.

```f#
module Option =
    let map2 f x y =
        match x,y with
        | Some x, Some y -> Some (f x y)
        | _ -> None
```

then you just can write:

```f#
items
|> List.map (fun line -> 
    line.Price 
    |> Option.map (fun price -> price * discount)
    |> Option.map2 (fun cost price -> price - cost) line.Cost 
    |> Option.map2 (fun qty price  -> price * qty) line.Qty)
```

and it will return:

```f#
[None; None; Some -21.250M; None; None]
```

Comment: After talking with a coworker, I ended up writing an `optionMap2` function before I saw this answer.

Comment: @Steven and what will happen when you have 3 options? Would you write ``map3``? Ok, that's just a detail but what about readability? I don't think that using forward pipe to do math formulas step by step reads well. Have a look at the alternatives me and others provided when all your math formula is in one place. I would recommend whichever solution you pick, have all the formula in one place and not split across different lines.

Answer (score 7):

You are mixing `decimal` with `decimal option`.

If you're trying to solve everything with `Option.map` you may want to try with `Option.bind` instead, so your code will be 'linearly nested':

```
items
|> Seq.map (    
    fun line ->
        Option.bind(fun price ->
          Option.bind(fun cost ->
             Option.bind(fun qty ->
                Some ((discount * price - cost ) * qty)) line.Qty) line.Cost) line.Price)
```

which can be an interesting exercise, especially if you want to understand [monads](https://www.google.com/#q=monads), then you will be able to use a [computation expression](https://www.google.com/#q=f%23+computation+expressions), you can create your own or use one from a library like [F#x](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras) or [F#+](https://github.com/gmpl/FSharpPlus):

```
open FSharpPlus.Builders

items |> Seq.map (fun line ->
    monad {
        let! price = line.Price
        let! cost = line.Cost
        let! qty = line.Qty
        return ((discount * price - cost ) * qty)
    }
)
```

but if you link F#+ you'll have Applicative Math Operators available:

```
open FSharpPlus.Operators.ApplicativeMath
items |> Seq.map (fun line -> ((discount *| line.Price) |-| line.Cost ) |*| line.Qty)
```

That's nice stuff to learn but otherwise I would suggest to use F# built-in features instead, like pattern-match, it would be easier:

```
items
|> Seq.map (fun line -> match line.Price, line.Qty, line.Cost with
                        | Some price, Some qty, Some cost -> 
                            Some ((discount * price - cost ) * qty)
                        | _ -> None)
```

Then since you can also pattern-match over records it can be further reduced to:

```
items
|> Seq.map (function 
            | {Cost = Some cost; Price = Some price; Qty = Some qty} ->
                Some ((discount * price - cost ) * qty)
            | _ -> None)
```

Note that `Option.map (fun x -> x)` doesn't transform anything.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `Option.map` the `x` is actually a decimal, but the signature for `Option.map` is `'T option -> 'U option`. So here:

```
Option.map (fun x -> x - (line.Cost |> Option.map (fun x -> x)))
```

you have the following:

```
Option.map (fun x -> /*decimal*/ x - /*decimal option*/(line.Cost |> Option.map (fun x -> x)))
```

So the `decimal option` has to be converted to decimal to be compatible with what's in the first `Option.map`. But now you have to deal with `None` result.

Below a quick (and nasty) fix that just is using an `if` statement to extract `Value` (which will be a decimal) or if `None` then return 0.

```
items
|> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Price
                    |> Option.map (fun x -> discount * x)
                    |> Option.map (fun x -> x - if line.Cost.IsSome then line.Cost.Value else 0m)
                    |> Option.map (fun x -> x * if line.Qty.IsSome then line.Qty.Value else 0m))
```

For a more sophisticated solution I recommend this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084247/3330348).

Comment: Why keep doing ``Option.map (fun x -> x)``?

Comment: Yeah, Agreed. Should be shortened. Fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, you may also leverage the monadic properties of the option type by "lifting" the values outside of the option. This is a somewhat simpler variant of the [applicative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084247/3330348) linked by [@PiotrWolkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708745/arithmetic-with-decimal-option-types/39709282#39709282) and those shown by [@Gustavo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708745/arithmetic-with-decimal-option-types/39709389#39709389). Applicatives not only wrap values in the monad, but also the functions applied to them.

We start by making the option type amenable to monadic operations in terms of `bind` and `return`. Thankfully, those functions are already defined, there's only a little tweak in the argument order.

```
let (>>=) ma f = Option.bind f ma
let ``return`` = Some
```

On top of this there's the `lift` function and a couple of operators for convenience. If needed, they could be generalized by marking them inline.

```
let liftOpt op x y =
    x >>= fun a ->
    y >>= fun b ->
    ``return`` (op a b)
let (.*) = liftOpt (*)
let (.-) = liftOpt (-)
```

Now your calculation becomes

```
items
|> Seq.map (fun line -> 
    (line.Price  .* Some discount .- line.Cost) .* line.Qty )
|> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

which will print

> ```
> <null>
> <null>
> Some -21.250M
> <null>
> <null>
> ```