# How to apply optional value to an optional function in F#

Tags: f#

In F# I have an optional function with signature `type func= (string-> string list) option`. How to pass an optional string parameter of signature `type param= string option` to the `func` method.

Is there any way to do this without using nested if else.

Comment: You can be quite elegant with match. Look into railway oriented programming

Comment: I smell applicatives? No? Shamelessly selfref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082719/how-to-multiply-two-double-options-in-f/39084247#39084247

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't notice right away that the function itself is *also* wrapped in `option`. I'll keep the original answer to misread question below for reference, but here's the answer for the *actual* question:

First, you still have to decide what you want to do when there is no function and/or no string (see below). Once you have the decision, you can just match on the tuple:

```
let resultingList =
   match func, param with
   | Some f, Some p -> f p  // When both are present, apply
   | _ -> []                // Otherwise, return empty list
```

Here, I collapse all cases when either one or both are absent. But if you need different behavior for these cases, you can enumerate all or some of them explicitly:

```
let resultingList =
   match func, param with
   | Some f, Some p -> f p 
   | Some f, None -> f ""
   | None, Some _ -> [ "there was no function" ]
   | None, None -> [ "there was no string AND no function" ]
```

---

#### The original answer to the misread question

The type `string option` means "*There may be a string here, or not*". So the first question to ask yourself is: what do you want to do when there is no string? I can't help you decide on this one, because this depends on your larger problem (i.e. what you are ultimately trying to do).

The function `string -> string list` takes a `string` and returns a `string list`. So if you have a string, then you get back a `string list`. But what if you don't have a `string`? Should you get back a "nothing" (i.e. "there is no list", just like "there was no string" to begin with)? Or should you get an empty list? Or should you get some predefined value?

For the sake of gradual learning, let's just assume that, when there is no string, you want to get back an empty list. To do this, use pattern matching:

```
let resultingList =
   match param with
   | Some s -> func s
   | None -> []
```

This program literally says: "*if there is a string, call that string `s` and apply `func` to it; and if there is no string, return an empty list*".

Same thing would apply to getting some other predefined list instead of the empty one:

```
let resultingList =
   match param with
   | Some s -> func s
   | None -> [ "oopsie, there was no string!" ]
```

But if you want the other option - the "there is no list" one, - then your resulting value will need to be `string list option`, just like your input is `string option`. The `option` type has two constructors: `Some` to create values that are present, and `None` to denote "there is no <strike>spoon</strike> value".

```
let maybeResultingList =
   match param with
   | Some s -> Some (func s)
   | None -> None
```

This literally says: "*if there is a string, call it `s`, apply `func` to it, and wrap the result as `Some`, which means "there is a list here"; and if there is no string, just return `None`, which means "there is no list*".

As luck would have it, this "*apply function to the value, unless it's not there*" operation is so common that there is a standard library function for it. It's called `Option.map`:

```
let maybeResultingList = Option.map func param
```

Another interesting way to look at it is this: first we pass `func` to `Option.map` and get back another function, and then we apply that function to `param`:

```
let maybeFunc = Option.map func
let maybeResultingList = maybeFunc param
```

This way of looking at it turns out to be very useful in practice. The venerable Scott Wlaschin has a totally kick-ass series on the concept. Check it out here: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/

Comment: I am getting ```func``` via Option.map only.

Comment: @Jigar: looks like I've misread the question. Updated the answer.